# how to use the JNI ThrowNew()?

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a method like this:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT  jint JNICALL
Java_tt_reducto_ndksample_StringTypeOps_exception
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj) {
    (env)->ExceptionClear();
    jclass exception_cls = (env)->FindClass("java/lang/IllegalArgumentException");
    (env)->ThrowNew(exception_cls, "key0 is not invalid");

    return -1;

}
```

it was worked. but if return jstring like this:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT  jstring JNICALL
Java_tt_reducto_ndksample_StringTypeOps_exception
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj) {

    (env)->ExceptionClear();
    jclass exception_cls = (env)->FindClass("java/lang/IllegalArgumentException");
    (env)->ThrowNew(exception_cls, "key0 is not invalid");
    return env->NewStringUTF("22");

}
```

it was crushed.

```
 JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI ThrowNew called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key0 is not invalid
```

i was try catch:

```
 try {
                 StringTypeOps.exception()
            }catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                Log.d("::","Exception")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

I'm not sure what the restrictions are on using the ThrowNew() function

Comment: You can't both throw an exception and return a value, just like you wouldn't be able to do that in Java code. After calling `ThrowNew` you shouldn't call any other JNI functions until the exception has been caught.

Comment: @Michael You can return anything you want after throwing an exception in the JVM (in fact, it's required in order to return out of the native method) but the value is ignored. The second sentence is the key -- most JNI methods cannot be called with a pending exception. It either needs to be handled using JNI or control flow needs to return back to Java code so it can be handled there.